# how secure is my code in phonegap

Tags: cordova

Phonegap allow us to build an app using **HTML, Javascript and CSS** and by uploading these file to them, they build several binary for us.
How secure code is if i upload my code to them as a private project. 
Will it accessible to others or any party to read my code?

Answer (score 2):

You can see phonegap [faq](http://build.phonegap.com/faq) in detail to get the idea about phonegap build program, from that website i found some useful information for you.

**Can I use PhoneGap Build with a private Github repository?**

Yes! As of the most recent update to PhoneGap Build, you can now point the service at a private GitHub repository. Once your Build account is connected to your GitHub account in the user settings, you simply provide your authentication information and the Build service uses it when creating new builds of your code.

**What is the difference between public and private apps?**

Public apps have their source code hosted in a publicly accessible GitHub repository. Private apps have their source code hosted in a private (non-publicly accessible) GitHub repository or are created when a developer uploads a ZIP file containing the source code and assets to the PhoneGap Build service.

**Where do I go to find PhoneGap Build help?**

Ask a question on our community forum: http://community.phonegap.com, or ask us on Twitter: http://twitter.com/PhoneGapBuild

You'll get more information about the security of the code here -[how_secure_is_my_code_on_phonegap_build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how_secure_is_my_code_on_phonegap_build)

Tips:

- Do not hard-code user's or server's credential inside the app.
- Avoid from permanently store/save user's or server's credential, give it encrypted or plain.
- Connect to your servers ONLY in SSL mode (https, ftps).
- Obfuscate every single source files whenever possible before uploading to Build.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. Another concern is that will PhoneGap access our code (even for private project)?